# kubernetes: providing explicit CIDRs for pods/services

Tags: kubernetes

A kubernetes cluster, unless I am wrong, incorporates 3 networks:

- the physical network connecting the master(s)/worker(s)
- a virtual network interconnecting the pods (where all pods can reach each other)
- a virtual network where the services are exposed

my question is whether at some point (i.e. when creating the cluster via say `kops`) one can provision for specific CIDRs for the two virtual nets

Answer (score 1):

when you execute `kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr 10.244.0.0/16`,You provision CIDR for pods network.this network used by Flunnel or other CNI addon for routable . But service IP not need routable

Comment: thanks. however I do not quite get the `service IP not need routable ` part. When you define a `ClusterIP` service type, doesn't it get a specific IP (from a different CIDR than the one assigned to the pods), via which it is reachable? (from within the cluster of course) ---- even this is a virtual IP (i.e. just an iptables entry), shouldn't it be still routable from within the cluster?